# pgadmin4 is very slow to open empty tables of database

Tags: performance, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I installed PostgreSQL 9.6.3-1 on my windows 10 laptop. The processor of my laptop is Intel(R)Core (TM)i7-5500U CPU @ 2.4GHZ and installed Memory is 8.00GB.
pgadmin 4 is too slow to open table of my databases. I have just made schema of table and i haven't import any data but it is slow to open my database.
What should I do? should I install any Prerequisite application or downgrade to pgadmin3?

Comment: pgAdmin4 is hybrid application, it is not pure desktop application like pgAdmin3, so it will run slower than pgAdmin3.

Comment: pgAdmin4 is based on web technologies (HTML, JavaScript etc.) and uses WebKit (as I remember) as its front-end. Thus it is inefficient by default. pgAdmin3 is the better choice (I hope that its support will not be dropped), or look for some [third-party clients](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools). Or, as an option, upgrade your hardware :o)

Comment: @n33rma is the error of pgadmin 4 desktop runtime has stopped working is because of that?

Comment: @Abelisto this error: pgadmin 4 desktop runtime has stopped working is because of my hardware.? because my database include 1 million quay.

Comment: Most probably...Yes.

On Desktop mode, pgAdmin4 is wrap under Qt4/5 WebEngine, most of the time its Qt which crashes and can't handle it.

If you want to take full advantage of pgAdmi4, I suggest you to install it on Web Server and use it from Browser.

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/1.x/server_deployment.html#

Comment: You can still download and use pgAdmin 3. It will give you a warning (because it supports PostgreSQL 8.4 to 9.5), but it will work with 9.6. That's what I do.

Comment: pgAdmin 3 is no longer supported and the developers recommended the use of the version 4. Unfortunately for this web-centric application designed to look like a desktop app, pgAdmin 4 is so slow. But at least it is usable. I really do not understand why do we need all web-centric apps these days.

Comment: pgAdmin v4 is terribly slow compared to v3. I noticed issues in pgAdmin 3 trying to create a table with a bigserial where the db was created in pgAdmin v4 (using postgres 9.6). So it seems some tasks may work in v3, while others may not work so well.

Comment: I'm upvoting just because I hate the slowliness of pgAdmin4 and because pgAdmin3 is not working with Postgres 10 :( (and because I don't like web apps used as desktop without a browser)

Answer (score 3):

I am confronted with the same problem by installing PostgreSQL 9.6. 
Just install [PgAdmin3 1.22.2](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin3/v1.22.2) and everything will become normal again

Comment: PgAdmin3 1.22.2 doesn't work properly with Windows 10 (several error messages on startup). In addition: almost no difference to pdAdmin 4 in terms of performance.